# removing mold on wall beneath sink

Tags: mold

I had some water dripping under the sink from the valve and the faucet that was leaking. After fixing the faucet, some mold started to appear on the dry wall behind the sink. I have taken it out two times, once with vinegar. However, it has come back again. How can I fix it ? Would it ever go?

[Full photo set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBwZV.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mold is recurring, there is still moisture in the drywall. Keep a fan on the area until it's completely dry, and clean the mold off one more time. Once that's done, you can prime and paint and the problem should not recur. You might use a primer that's marketed as a good stain blocker.

Comment: is a heater required or just fan would work?

Comment: Also any advice on how to remove ? (should i add some commercial liquid)

Comment: Spritz it with a spray bottle containing 1 tablespoon of bleach per quart of cold water to kill the fungus first, then scrub it off after it's dried. You can purchase commercial sanitizers at the local kitchen supply house, if you're really opposed to mixing your own.